# How a single byte can hold -128 value

Tags: c, binary-data

In memory 128 will be stored as `10000000`.  Where should I place the sign bit here since whole 1 byte is occupied by number 128 if i store -128 in byte datatype?

Can you please explain me?

Comment: I am talking about -128

Comment: i am talking about -128 in 1 byte

Answer (score 10):

Signed integers are typically represented in **two's complement**.  This means that for a given positive number, the corresponding negative number is obtained by inverting all bits then adding 1.

A negative number in two's complement will have the high order bit set.  This bit becomes the sign bit.

So for a number occupying a single byte, `11111111` represents -1, `11111110` represents -2, and so forth, all the way to `10000000` which represents -128.  On the high end, `01111111` represents 127.

This means that a 1 byte signed integer cannot store the value 128.  If you had a 1 byte *unsigned* integer then `10000000` would be 128 but then it could not hold any negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

A single byte means 8 bits, which mean you can choose from 2^8 = 256 values. In C representation for signed char (or signed integer of 1 byte) teh values chosen were from [-128, 127] including both extremes

Comment: Note that a single byte in C does not have to be 8 bits. It has to be a _minimum_ of 8 bits wide, and the ranges for other numeric types are similarly defined as minimum ranges. C does not specify a range of [-128, 127] for a `signed char`; it specifies as a minimum range for `signed char` [-127, 127] and allows implementations to choose from sign and magnitute, one's complement, or two's complement representations.

Comment: Yes sir, you're very right, feel free to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could cast to unsigned char, like

```c
char s128 = (char)128;
if((unsigned char)s128==128){
    printf("true\n");
}
```